# How to Know Video Status using ffmpeg

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg

i am working on video transcoding using ffmpeg. ffmpeg video transcoding engine always work internally,but i have a video url on frontend. so i could not play video untill it complete. so how can i get status of video,how much it is completed to help end user to play video ?

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c",ffmpegCommand);
        processBuilder.start();
```

ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i weblogic4.mp4 -b:v 180k -bufsize 180k output.mkv
```